# C#: Using a referenced DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference

I've created a DLL and referenced it to my project, but I cannot figure out how to actually use it. It appears that to make it work, I have to use some code like

```
MyClass class = new MyClass;
```

But I still can't get it to work. Here's my code:

```
using MyClass;  
namespace NoName  
{  
    public partial class Form1 : Form  
    {  
        public Form1()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
        }  

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyClass MyClass = new MyClass();
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(MainImage.Image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're question makes no sense. It's really unclear as to what your real problem is. Do you not know how to add a reference in your project? Do you not know how to use the `using` statement? etc...

Comment: When you ask a question, don't just say vague things like "can't get it to work." Do you think that's helpful to us at all?

Comment: "I've created a DLL and referenced it to my project". I just need to know how to... I don't know how to put this... declare it? I can reference and "using" it just fine, but I can't actually use the class in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have referenced the namespace that holds the types you want to use from your class library in the dependent program.

```
using <Namespace of MyClass>;

public static void Main()
{
   MyClass blah = new MyClass();
}
```

In most cases the root namespace you are looking for should match the name of your referenced dll. e.g. DLLName.xxx ... where "DLLName" would be your root namespace and the anything after the period would signify child folders in a continuing hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wan to add a reference to your class namespace (by means of the **using** reserved word) then you can completely qualified your class when you create an instance of it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    MyClassNameSpace.MyClass MyClass = new MyClassNameSpace.MyClass(); 
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(MainImage.Image); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you create your instance of your class your variable name needs to not be the same case as your class.

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

now you can use

```
myClass.MyMethod(x, y)
```

In your code posting your were using

```
MyClass MyClass = new MyClass();
```

If this is not the actual problem then give us an example of how you want to use MyClass (what methods or properties does it have?)

Answer (score 0):

You should have `using MyClassNamespace;` where `MyClassNamespace` is the namespace of `MyClass`.